# How can I convert a dictionary table to a list table in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
def change_table(table):

    """
    (dict) -> table
```

return a table list from a dictionary list where the table list lists are the rows of the items

```
change_table({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1, 2, 3]})

>>> [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
"""

table_list = []
item_table = []
item_row = []

column_row = []

for key in table:
    column_row.append(key)
    i = 0
    for item in range(len(table[key])):


        item_table.append(table[key][item])

        item_row.insert(i, item_table)
        i = i + 1

table_list.extend(column_row)
table_list.extend(item_row)
return table_list
```

This doesn't do what I want it to do. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Waht are you going to do? Don't understand the question ...

Answer (score 1):

```
[[key for key in table.keys()]] + [[val[i] for val in table.values()] for i in range(len(table.values()[0]))]
```

Edit: The comment below is valid, the key order is not the same as it is in the original table, however column order is preserved. Using sorted(keys) will disrupt the order:

```
table = {'a':['a1','a2','a3'],'b':['b1','b2','b3'],'c':['1','2','3']}
[[key for key in sorted(table.keys())]] + [[val[i] for val in table.values()] for i in range(len(table.values()[0]))]
>>>[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a1', '1', 'b1'], ['a2', '2', 'b2'], ['a3', '3', 'b3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2:

```
def change_table(d):
    values = d.values()
    return sorted(d.keys()) + [[item[i] for item in values] 
                          for i in range(len(values[0]))]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(change_table({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1, 2, 3]}))
```

...or Python 3:

```
def change_table(d):
    values = list(d.values())
    return [sorted(d.keys())] + [[item[i] for item in values] 
                                for i in range(len(values[0]))]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(change_table({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1, 2, 3]}))
```